# Кто нибудь может поделиться опытом, как мапить PagedList на PagedList с AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Я пытаюсь следовать этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962033/7542937). Но то что там предложено, не работает. Или я не понимаю до конца, как оно должно работать. 
Итак, у меня задача. Смапить PagedList объектов бизнес-логики на PagedList объектов view модели.

Вот мой метод действия контроллера:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int pageNumber = 1, bool showActive = true)
{
    var manuallySendings = _dbContext.ManuallySendings
        .Include(x => x.Messages)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.PushLang).Where(x => x.IsActive == showActive);

    var manuallySendingsPagedList = await manuallySendings.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, 15);


    var viewModelsPagedList =  _mapper.Map<IPagedList<ManuallySending>, IPagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>(manuallySendingsPagedList);
    return View(viewModelsPagedList);
}
```

Вот профайл для мапинга бизнес-объекта на модель представления

```
public class ManuallySendingToManuallySendingIndexPageItem : Profile
{
    public ManuallySendingToManuallySendingIndexPageItem()
    {
        CreateMap<ManuallySending, ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PackageIds,
                opt 
                    => opt.MapFrom(x => x.PackageIds))
            // more .ForMember ...
            .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>();
    }
}
```

И, обратите внимание, на вызов в конце `ConvertUsing`. Он же должен объяснить автомапперу, как мапить этот тип, верно?

А вот мой кстомный конвертор:

```
public class PagedListConverter : ITypeConverter<PagedList<ManuallySending>,PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>
{
    public PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel> Convert(PagedList<ManuallySending> source, 
        PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var vm = source.Select(m 
            => context.Mapper.Map<ManuallySending, ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>(m)).ToList();

        return new PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>(vm, source.PageNumber, source.PageSize);
    }
}
```

Но я даже запустить это не могу. IDE говорит мне:

> ManuallySendingToManuallySendingIndexPageItem.cs(18, 18): [CS0311] Тип "AdminPanel.Automapper.PagedListConverter" не может быть использован как параметр типа "TTypeConverter" в универсальном типе или методе "IMappingExpressionBase>.ConvertUsing()". Нет преобразования неявной ссылки из "AdminPanel.Automapper.PagedListConverter" в "AutoMapper.ITypeConverter".

Нажимаю alt + enter пользуюсь подсказкой. Мне предлагается изменить интерфейс конвертора с `ITypeConverter<PagedList<ManuallySending>,PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>` на `ITypeConverter<ManuallySending, ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>`

Но как я из этого сделаю PagedList? Не понимаю :( Помогите, пожалуйста. Думаю, решение поможет многим, кто на это наткнется в дальнейшем.

P.S Я использую автомаппер последней версии и .net core 3.1. Все самое новое.

Comment: Что то у вас каша какая то. Вы конвертировать пытаетесь `IPagedList<>`, конвертер у вас для `PagedList`, а использовать вы его пытаетесь для конвертации просто моделей. Поглядите на свой код и на код по вашей ссылке и найдите минимум 3 отличия.

Comment: @tym32167 Здравствуйте! Знал, что вы ответите)) Спасибо вам за это! О каких именно отличиях вы говорите? Я посмотрел лучше и теперь я понял, что мне нужно иметь два профайла. Первый - это модель на вью модель, второй - пэджед лист на пэйджет лист. Вот такой вот, как у него в ответе указано `Mapper.CreateMap<PagedList<Item>, PagedList<ItemViewModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>();`  Предполагаю, что в первом я должен описать правила мапинга модели на вью модель, а второй будет без всяких.ForMember() просто вызвать ` .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter>()`. Я попробую это.

Comment: Ну и имейте ввиду, что тут у вас ipagedlist - интерфейс `_mapper.Map<IPagedList<ManuallySending>, IPagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>`, а тут у вас pagedlist - класс `PagedListConverter : ITypeConverter<PagedList<ManuallySending>,PagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>`, а интерфейс и класс - это разные типы.

Comment: @tym32167 да, действительно, я поспешил с вопросом, это было очевидно. Все работает и легко мапится. Ответ: внимательно посмотреть на инфу по ссылке, что я закрепил в начале. Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, после некоторого ресерча и микса нескольких решений со SO я пришел вот к такому "дженерик" конвертору и способу его использования.

1) Обязательно иметь обычный профайлер business object -> view model object. Смотрите подробности в документации [вот ссылка](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances).

2) Сделаем еще один профайлер, где объясним мапперу, что мы хотим не просто эти объекты мапить, а их paged листы. Согласно моему нейменгу и коду из вопроса, он у меня выглядит так:

```
public class PagedListToPagedList : Profile
{
    public PagedListToPagedList()
    {
        CreateMap<IPagedList<ManuallySending>, IPagedList<ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>()
            .ConvertUsing<PagedListConverter<ManuallySending, ManuallySendingIndexViewModel>>();
    }
}
```

3) А теперь самое интересное. Видите, мы тут сказали автомапперу, что конвертр будем использовать? (вызов `ConvertUsing`). Напишем этот дженерик конвертр. Он у меня вот такой получился.

```
public class
    PagedListConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<IPagedList<TSource>, IPagedList<TDestination>>
    where TSource : class where TDestination : class
{
    public IPagedList<TDestination> Convert(IPagedList<TSource> source,
        IPagedList<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var vm = source.Select(m
            => context.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(m)).ToList();

        return new StaticPagedList<TDestination>(vm, source.GetMetaData());
    }
}
```

В отличии о того способа, что указан по ссылке на англоязычный SO в моем вопросе, тут у меня не теряется количество страниц и пагинация отрабатывает корректно! Всем спасибо, надеюсь, что это кому то поможет!

Comment: Только, единственная проблема, я не разобрался, как бы мне мой "дженерик" конвертр вынести в отдельный проект (Infrastructure например). При его использовании возникает ошибка `Cannot create an instance of type ...`